# Using HTML tags in CartoDB

Tags: html, sql, cartodb

I'm trying to use [CartoDB](http://www.cartodb.com) to create an interactive map, where people can click on a location, and pop up (in CartoDB on the map) explaining some details about that location will open up.

Right now, I have it all working, I import my CSV with the locations, and the names of those locations, and another column for the content of the pop up for those locations.  In the editor, I have it all working, I've used the custom HTML feature for the pop ups and just have it pull in information from that column for displaying.

What I'm having trouble with is how to format that text that is pulled in for the pop up.  I'd like to have more control in it by using HTML tags (i.e. 
, , ) on certain words in the text.  Since they're different for each pop up, I can't just add it to the CartoDB editor where it pulls in the text for the pop ups.

I tried asking the CartoDB representative I have, and he didn't know the answer and just told me to ask on StackOverflow instead (not extremely helpful of him)...

Here's a link to my map as it is now:

https://iongeo.cartodb.com/viz/9ee487e4-817b-11e4-8caa-0e853d047bba/public_map

Comment: Looks like [this was added](http://blog.cartodb.com/full-editing-of-infowindow-html/) back in '03

Comment: I'm already using that.  I attached a link to my map so you can see that I am already using the custom HTML for the info window... that's not my problem... I can't add/use tags in the data that is stored in the SQL field.

Comment: The link mentions using their js library along with Mustache for dynamic markup - you currently use that?

Comment: No I'm not, and reading over that, I'm not sure that I even understand it.  Could you help me with a little more direction to accomplish what I'm wanting to do here?

What I'm currently doing is this:
Here is what I have in the SQL table under dp_center_info.
http://i.imgur.com/i1SumB2.png

Comment: What I'm currently doing is this  |  Here is what I have in the SQL table under dp_center_info: 
http://i.imgur.com/i1SumB2.png |  And here is what I have in the infoWindow Custom HTML: http://i.imgur.com/Mn2IAsB.png  |  But still, I'm getting this in my pop ups: http://i.imgur.com/rktkgBn.png

Comment: Could you please move your question to gis.stackexchange.com, with cartodb tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, CartoDB does not have this ability currently.  I spoke with their dev team and they are currently working to add it.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a few months old, but there's no real answer and it's one of the first hits for CartoDB/Mustache google searches, and it looks like your demo map is still not working.

The answer is actually straight forward - Mustache automatically escapes HTML but the easy fix is to use three tags instead of two, like so:
{{{ContentwithHTML}}}

The documentation for Mustache is here: https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html

Comment: Thanks Zizania, but we ended up abandoning using CartoDB for a more user friendly option that had that functionality built into the CMS portion of the tool.